# How to Calculate Total Variation (TV) of an Image?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, total-variation

TV is L1 norm of gradient of an image. So we've to find gradient of the image (which is still matrix, right?). Then take the sum of absolute values of the gradient matrix (So now it must be a scalar, right?).

Can I simply use `imgradient` function in matlab for first step? It gives two values magnitude and direction, so which one should I consider for next step?

After getting gradient matrix say `Igrad`, will just summing absolute values (`sum(abs(Igrad(:)))` give me TV? And it must be just a single scalar value right?

Thank you for reading. Keenly waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Total Variation of an image $I$ can be computed using two formulas:

- $TV(I) = \sum_{x} \| \nabla I (x) \|_1 $ (anisotropic TV);
- $TV(I) = \sum_{x} \sqrt{ \| \nabla I (x) \|_2^2 }$ (isotropic TV).

In practice, both formulas yield almost the same result.

Using matlab, what you propose implements the first formula, while the second one can be obtained by `sqrt(gradI_x.^2 + gradI_y.^2)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have one more query. Since the result of TV is scalar how are we adding it as a regularization term in many image restoration problems? Because images and other parameters are matrices. I don't know if this is proper place to ask this. Anyway thanks again

Comment: Two solutions that have the same data fidelity score will probably have different TV score. Thus, among the possible solutions, the one with the lowest TV is kept.

Comment: I have a related inquiry. How can we calculate DTV (differential total variation) using Matlab?

Comment: @Mohammadnagdawi, Have a look on my answer here - https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/57985/128. There is a MATLAB code.

Answer (score 0):

can use MATLAB function imgradientxy.

> [Gx,Gy] = imgradientxy(I).

This will return the x and y derivative of image I.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).